# Jquery mobile : popup removed from DOM

Tags: dom, jquery-mobile, caching, popup

In my JQUerymobile pages, I have embedded popup div.
Here is an example of my pages content :

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>  
  <body>
     <div data-role="page" id="myPage" data-dom-cache="true"  data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" >...</div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-id="footer-sante" data-position="fixed">...</div>
            <div data-role="popup" id="popupOne" data-dom-cache="true" data-theme="b">

        </div>

     </div>
     <div data-role="popup" id="popupTwo" data-dom-cache="true" data-theme="b">
    ...
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I navigate from pages to anothers. Suddently, my embedded popups disappear from my DOM when I inspect my code.

As shown in my example, the popup location in the source code doesn't seem to change anything to the problem.

Since popups are removed from DOM, the code bellow does nothing (it actually worked before) :

```
    $('#popupOne').trigger('create');
    $('#popupOne').popup({ transition: "slidedown", position:"position-header" });
    $('#popupOne').popup('open');
```

**Is there a solution to keep my popups in my DOM ?**

- Is there a better location to embed popups in source code ?
- Another way could be to load a popup from an external (cached) page but i never achieved to do that by javascript.

Any idea to solve the problem (or a workaround) ?

Comment: You want to use same popup for several pages? Why are you enhancing popup while its already in DOM `$('#popupOne').trigger('create');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Both) your HTML placements might be incorrect here. Remove the `popupOne` markup from the end of the page and paste it inside the `div` with `data-role=content` like this :

```
 <div data-role="page" id="myPage" data-dom-cache="true"  data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" >
         <div data-role="popup" id="popupOne" data-dom-cache="true" data-theme="b"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-id="footer-sante" data-position="fixed">...</div>       
 </div>
```

And if you want to reuse popups, I suggest you go the JS way. You could create popups n the fly and open them. Here's some code which does just that. Feel free to alter it to any thing you want :)

```
$.extend({
    "makePopup": function (text) {
        var $popup;
        //creat popup element
        $popup = $("<div/>", {
            "data-role": "popup",
                "data-theme": "a",
                "data-overlay-theme": "a",
                "data-transition": "pop"
        }).popup();
        //create close element
        var $close = $("<a/>", {
            "data-role": "button",
                "html": "Close",
                "href": "#",
                "data-theme": "e"
        }).on("click", function () {
            //click event of close element
            $(this).closest("[data-role=popup]").popup("close");
        }).buttonMarkup();

        //create content div - makes a nice jQM page structure.
        var $content = $("<div/>", {
            "data-role": "content",
            //change this any way you want- Im just adding the text from clicked link here.
            "html": "<span>" + text + "</span>"
        });

        //append $close to $content, then append $content to $popup
        $content.append($close).appendTo($popup);
        return $popup;
    }

});
```

And when you want to use this, just do this,

```
 var popupEl = $.makePopup("Some HTML");
```

And then you could, say, open it :

```
 popupEl.popup("open");
```

Or simply,

```
 $.makePopup("Some HTML").popup("open");
```

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/xjz3V/

Hope this is what you wanted :)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your example. It works very well until, i want to add style in the div which data-role="content". 
.popup() , .trigger('create'), .trigger('pagecreate')... doesn't seem to change anything. "header" and "content" are not parsed by JQM and style aren't added to the generated DOM. Any idea ?